# Change content page after form submit Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

I am trying to add some Javascript functionality to my symfony project, but have little Javascript experience.

I have a form at `/login` and after the submit it redirects to `/account` but the header page is the same. 
I want to change the header after the submit of my form.

This is what I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".form-login").submit(function() {
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/account",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function() {
    $(".account:first").text("My account");
    $(".account:first").text("Disconnect");
   }
})
```

It works during the load of the page but when I'm at `/account` it is still the same header.

Comment: Issues with this code aside, it sounds like server side includes would be much better suited to what you need.

Comment: if you redirect to account, why not submitting your form to account, check the login credentials and redirect back to login if unsuccesfull or continue loading the account page if successfull?

Comment: Try to check user logged in or not in account page and change the header menu accordingly in account page

Answer (score 0):

can used this code :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".form-login").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8000/account",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $(".account:first").text("My account");
                    $(".account:first").text("Disconnect");
               }
        })
    })
})
```

or

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".form-login").submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8000/account",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $(".account:first").text("My account");
                    $(".account:first").text("Disconnect");
               }
        });
 return false;
    });
})
```